# v-for loop show only most recent upload

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

In our app, users need to be able to upload a copy of their driver's license to their profile. Then if they need to update their license, they upload another one. However, users should only see their most recent upload.

Our v-for loop:

```
<div v-for="(license, index) in licenses.slice(0, 1)" :key="license.id">
       <img :src="license.licenseUrl" class="upload" />
      </div>
```

db call:

```
firestore () {
return {
  user: db.collection('users').doc(this.userAuth.id),
  uploads: db.collection('users').doc(this.userAuth.id).collection('uploads'),
  licenses: db.collection('users').doc(this.userAuth.id).collection('licenses')
}
},
```

And vuex:

```
db.collection('users').doc(payload.profile).collection('licenses').add({
        licenseUrl: downloadURL,
        uploaded: createdAt
      })
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why use `v-for` here? If you only want to rende one license, can you not just use a computed property? (Or if the license you want to render is at index 0, just reference that directly.)

Comment: Yeah I can just do this: <img :src="licenses[0].licenseUrl" class="upload" />, but I am still having a problem where the order is wrong. When I add my images to firebase and my download urls to firestore, each of the images is a doc in my "licenses" collection. The doc ids are random. So the most recent image I upload isn't necessarily the index [0]. If that makes any sense...

Comment: If your issue is that your licenses array is not in the right order (which I'm guessing from your last comment here, it's not clear at all what the actual issue you're having is), then the way to solve this would be to have your DB call order the records it's returning, which is most definitely possible with any competent DB. Though I'm not sure how to do it in your case specifically since I've never worked with firestore, you can surely find documentation on it with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Stephan Thomas in his comment, I would emphasize on not using v-for in this case.

A v-for renders your views on a loop therefore all items on your `licenses` variable will be rendered. Since you'd like to show ONLY the most recent upload, I suggest you grab it by the index manually.

Assuming licenses is an `Array` and the required item is at index 0, use something like:

`<div v-if="licenses.length > 0"> <!-- check if array not empty -->
   <img :src="licenses[0]" class="upload" /> <!-- get access -->
</div>`